# Stop UserScript from automatically clicking

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

The code below is part of a JavaScript UserScript I'm creating to add comment buttons on a specific subreddit on Reddit:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Assholedesign Repost Commenter
// @namespace    Reddit
// @version      0.1
// @description  Add repost buttons to r/assholedesign
// @author       Duncan Yang
// @include      https://*.reddit.com/r/assholedesign/comments/*
// @include      http://*.reddit.com/r/assholedesign/comments/*
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var edit_form = document.querySelector("form > div.usertext-edit").parentNode;
    var btns = edit_form.querySelector("div.usertext-edit > div.bottom-area > div.usertext-buttons");
    var save_btn = btns.querySelector("button.save");
    var edit_textbox = edit_form.querySelector("div.usertext-edit > div > textarea");

    var repost_text = function(a) {
        edit_textbox.value = a;
        console.log(a);
    }

    try
    {
        var cancel_btn = btns.querySelector("button.cancel");

        var a00 = document.createElement("button");
        var a01 = document.createElement("button");
        var a02 = document.createElement("button");

        // This section of code is
        a00.setAttribute("class", "save");
        a00.innerHTML = "Repost";
        a00.addEventListener("click", repost_text("Repost"));
        a01.setAttribute("class", "save");
        a01.innerHTML = "General Repostii";
        a01.addEventListener("click", repost_text("[General Repostii](https://reddit.com/r/assholedesign/wiki/common_topics)"));
        a02.setAttribute("class", "save");
        a02.innerHTML = "Cold One";
        a02.addEventListener("click", repost_text("[General Repostii, you are a cold one.](https://reddit.com/r/assholedesign/wiki/common_topics)"));
        // where I am having problems.

        btns.insertBefore(a00, cancel_btn);
        btns.insertBefore(a01, cancel_btn);
        btns.insertBefore(a02, cancel_btn);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
}, false);
```

This script is currently disabled, because it has a problem of automatically clicking one or more of the buttons right when the page is loaded. How could I fix this so that the false clicks are no more?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `addEventListener` callback which runs immediately.

The callback in functions such as `addEventListener`, need to be a function that doesn't run immediately.

For example, the following will `alert('Hello')` as soon as the code is injected.

```
target.addEventListener('click', alert('Hello'));
```

However, the right way is to wrap it in a function like this:

```
target.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('Hello'); });
```

Above will only run after the event is fired.

In your code, the following will run immediately.

```
a00.addEventListener("click", repost_text("Repost"));
```

Change it to:

```
a00.addEventListener("click", function() { repost_text("Repost"); });
```

Or arrow function:

```
a00.addEventListener("click", () => repost_text("Repost"));
```

Just for info, if you didn't want to pass data to the function, the following would have been fine too:

```
a00.addEventListener("click", repost_text);
```